# How to remove dynamically added userform controls one at a time?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm building a workout logging application that allows the user to add a movement, number of reps, and the associated weight while the userform is running. (You can also think of it as "order-picking" eg. "3" "red" "pencils", "2" "blue" "markers", etc.)

The code adds the two textboxes and the combo box when the "+" button is clicked.

When the "-" button is clicked, only the last added group of controls will be deleted but if the "-" button is clicked again I'll get the "Catastrophic Failure" error message.

I'm pretty sure these controls need to be deleted using `controls.remove (object).name` but once that last group is deleted, I'll need to update the object variable to the next group that could be removed which I'm struggling with.

I found similar questions on here with answers, but those deleted all userform controls. I only want to remove the last group added.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public movementCounter As Integer
Public repsTextBox As Object
Public movementComboBox As Object
Public weightTextBox As Object
Public cntrlsColl As Collection

Private Sub addMvmtCmndButt_Click()

    movementCounter = movementCounter + 1

    Set repsTextBox = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    Set movementComboBox = Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    Set weightTextBox = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

    With repsTextBox
        .Name = "RepsTextBox" & movementCounter
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 45
        .Left = 10
        .Top = 30 * (movementCounter - 1) + 5
    End With

    With movementComboBox
        .Name = "MovementComboBox" & movementCounter
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 90
        .Left = 65
        .Top = 30 * (movementCounter - 1) + 5
        .RowSource = listsSht.Range("movementList").Address
    End With

    With weightTextBox
        .Name = "WeightTextBox" & movementCounter
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 45
        .Left = 165
        .Top = 30 * (movementCounter - 1) + 5
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub deleteMvmtCmndButt_Click()

'Works, but only for the most recently added group of controls
    With Me.Controls
        .Remove repsTextBox.Name
        .Remove movementComboBox.Name
        .Remove weightTextBox.Name
    End With

'update what the next group of controls will be on-deck
'    If movementCounter > 0 Then
'        repsTextBox.Name = "RepsTextBox" & movementCounter
'        movementComboBox.Name = "MovementComboBox" & movementCounter
'        weightTextBox.Name = "WeightTextBox" & movementCounter
'    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code...

```
Private Sub deleteMvmtCmndButt_Click()

    If movementCounter > 0 Then
        With Me.Controls
            .Remove "RepsTextBox" & movementCounter
            .Remove "MovementComboBox" & movementCounter
            .Remove "WeightTextBox" & movementCounter
        End With
        movementCounter = movementCounter - 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I seem to think I tried that already, but I'll for sure give it a go tomorrow and follow up. Thanks

Comment: If you're referring to the code you commented out in deleteMvmtCmndButt_Click(), it's not quite the same code.

Comment: I was all around the solution, just couldn't land on it. Your code works like a charm. Why did the `.name` property not need to be referenced?

Comment: To reference the Name property, you would need to know the control's name.  With repsTextBox.Name, repsTextBox does not refer to a textbox, since they're being named repsTextBox1, repsTextBox2, etc.